# In app update which with own server and not using Google Playstore is not working

Tags: android

I need to download and update my Android application which is not in Google Playstore. I have this in my MainActivity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        manager = AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(this);
        task = manager.getAppUpdateInfo();
        task.addOnSuccessListener(appUpdateInfo -> {
            if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setTitle("Update Alert!");
                builder.setMessage("Kindly update your application");
                builder.setPositiveButton("Update", (dialogInterface, i) -> {
                    try {
                        Intent intent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://some_ip_address/api/downloadables" +getPackageName());
                       intent1.setData(uri);
                       intent1.setPackage("net.sample.sampleupdater");
                       startActivity(intent1);
                    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
                builder.show();
            }
        });

        mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        mIntentFilter.addAction(mBroadcastStringAction);
        mIntentFilter.addAction(mBroadcastIntegerAction);
        mIntentFilter.addAction(mBroadcastArrayListAction);
        mIntentFilter.addAction(mBroadcastBooleanAction);

        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, InternetConnectionBackgroundService.class);
        startService(serviceIntent);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, CommonBoundService.class);
        bindService(intent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

        PrinterService.getInstance().initSunmiPrinterService(this);

        mainActivityViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainActivityViewModel.class);
    }
```

When I use the debugger, I can see that it gets to the end of the line without errors but the `task.addOnSuccessListener(...)` is not triggered. I actually do not know when would be the "Success Listener" be triggered. Would the "Success Listener" be triggered if it sees a package or something at the Google Play Store?. The Alert Dialog is not being fired. How can I do this correctly?

Comment: You are going too quick. Tell all. Is the on success listener triggered? And then the rest.

Comment: Sorry about that @blackapps. Please see my edit.

Comment: The success listener would be triggered when the task is done.

Comment: If the on success listener is not triggered then it makes no sense to complain about an alert dialog that you do not see. As that code is not executed then.

Comment: There is no code that starts the task.

Comment: `mIntentFilter = new ...` It is unclear for what you need that. And for what you need all following code. Is it relevant for your problem? If not, remove as only confusing.

Comment: Am not complaining about the onsuccess alert. Am confused why it is not triggered. Meaning why it is not succeeding. What need to be done to ensure its success. Or better yet, to steart downloading the application.

Comment: You did not post doewnload code. And the task is not started.